Issue with double quotes inside double quotes in JSON
I have a shell script part of which is the following JSON:
curl --request POST \
  --url 'https://'$jira_instance'.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/field/'$field_ID'/context/'$context_ID'/option' \
  --user $jira_user'@whatever.com:'$api_token \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{
  "options": [
    {
      "disabled": false,
      "value": "'$1'"
    }
  ]
}'

This only works if $1 contains no spaces.
If $1 contains any space(s) then I get the following error that tells me cURL is breaking:

curl: (3) unmatched close brace/bracket in URL position 11:

I have also tried with double quotes inside double quotes (""$1"") but this doesn't do anything at all.
Kindly advise.

Generally, within single quotes you quote variables like this: '"$1"'. In your case, try "value": "'"$1"'"

@dbran Kindly post this as a proper answer and I shall accept immediately.

Generally, to properly quote a variable within single quotes in Bash, use '"$var"' (single quote followed by double quote). The
first single quote ends the single-quoted string, then there's the double-quoted variable, and the second single quote restarts the single-quoted string.
Without the double-quotes, the parameter expansion is subject to word splitting, and spaces will split the text into multiple arguments to curl, causing it to treat the second one as a URL to fetch.
Given your example, this is how you should do it:
"value": "'"$1"'"

The extra quotes are removed by Bash, so if $1 is, say, one two, the final output would look like the following:
"value": "one two"

(Note that the variable value can't contain double quotes or they must be properly escaped.)

Your immediate issue is with quoting.  The first single quote in "value": "'$1'" ends the single-quoted string that makes up the argument to the --data option of curl. This makes the shell split the option argument on any space in the value of $1 (and apply filename globbing to each generated string).
Instead, don't inject shell variables into JSON documents.  Otherwise, you will have issues with strings containing double quotes and literal newlines or tabs.
Generate a shell variable that holds the payload separately using a JSON-aware tool such as jq. The jq utility knows how to encode a shell string correctly for use in a JSON document.
The following creates a shell variable, payload, which holds the JSON document that will be used with curl.
payload=$(
    jq -n \
        --arg value "$1" \
        '{ options: [ { disabled: false, value: $value } ] }'
)

or,
payload=$(
    jq -n \
        --argjson disabled false \
        --arg value "$1" \
        '{ options: [ $ARGS.named ] }'
)

Then use this with --data:
curl --request POST \
  --url "https://$jira_instance.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/field/$field_ID/context/$context_ID/option" \
  --user "$jira_user@whatever.com:$api_token" \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data "$payload"

(Note the other instances of corrected quoting in the above command!)
If $1 is set to the single string
this is a "quoted
newline"

then this would generate the following well-formed JSON document in $payload:
{
  "options": [
    {
      "disabled": false,
      "value": "this is a \"quoted\nnewline\""
    }
  ]
}

